# Can vba format tables by columns rather than by rows or individual cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, powerpoint-2010

I have vba in an Excel 2010 workbook, that creates Powerpoint 2010 slides. These slides contain tables that are populated from identical tables in the Excel workbook.

I want to apply alignment, number formatting, and margins (at least for starters) to the cells in the PP slide tables.

I have found solutions to format the table cells by walking through the rows and formatting each cell in that row one at a time, but my tables are typically column oriented so that makes the row solution undesirable (and slow).

This is my current, row-oriented code:

```
Set shapetable = activeSlide.Shapes.AddTable(numRows, 8)
With shapetable
    With .Table
       For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
          For Each cl In .Rows(iRow).Cells
             With cl.Shape.TextFrame
                .TextRange.Font.Size = "8"
                .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
             End With
          Next cl
       Next iRow
    End With
End With
```

Is it not possible to simply walk across the columns of the table and set these formats "per column"?

Comment: instead of generating a table in PPT, could you instead embed an excel document in the PPT thus inheriting the excel column formats already applied?

Comment: You can walk across the columns then down the cells in each column, but I figure you know this. I don't see any way to format all of the cells in a column (or row) at one whack, though. That should be .TextRange.Font.Size = 8 by the way (no quotes around the 8 ... it's a single, not a string)